VScode running python code error: [Done] exited with code=127 in 0.007 seconds
I am going crazy with this problem which i am not sure how to solve, I run python code in vscode and everything was fine, I restarted my macbook then opened the same file I was working on, when I run the code I get an error: [Running] python -u "/Users/fadi/Desktop/test.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found
[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.007 seconds
I reinstalled python in my macbook and vscode but still getting the error.
python3 --version 3.12.2
Help Please!
I am not expert programmer.
reinstalling python to the latest version

There is no executable called python in your PATH

1. on VSCode use the shortcut CMD + Shift  + P.

2. It opens up a command palette search bar, type Select Interpreter, and click on the Python:Select Interpreter option.

3. From there, You can choose python version you have installed.


Is looks like your system is unable to locate the Python interpreter. You can try these ways to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:
Firstly, make sure Python is installed correctly and installation path is added to your system's PATH environment variable. Check it by using which python3 in your terminal. It will show the path to the Python executable if everything is fine.
Then, check the VSCode side. VSCode may not have updated PATH after a new installation. Try restarting VSCode or manually updating the settings. Go to VSCode settings (cmd + ,), search for "Python Path", and set it to the path of your Python installation (e.g., /usr/local/bin/python3). It should solve the issues you are facing.
